# Display message after back button is pressed in Android

Tags: android

I have used the following code to go to other activity when back button is pressed.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent in = new Intent("com.test.START");
        startActivity(in);
    }
```

How should I edit the code so as to show a dialog box which asks the user to go back or stay in the current activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, per your code you are not going back, you start another activity, but anyway it can be done as following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    (new AlertDialog.Builder(this))
            .setTitle("Confirm action")
            .setMessage("Do you want to ...?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent in = new Intent("com.test.START");
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code:

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
           new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)  // icon that you want
                    .setTitle(R.string.alarm)  // title of your dialog
                    .setMessage(R.string.confirmedMessage)  // message of dialog
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,  // String for positive 
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                   // do positive action here

                                    finish();
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, // String for negative action
                                     null).show();

}
```

for going back you can use **finish()** method instead of start another activity